# Meaning of "Degree of approval" in a recommendation letter

Tags: recommendation-letter, terminology

Anybody knows what degree of approval means in a letter of reference?

- Emphatic
- Conditional
- Without concerns

My friend has a letter of reference from her former lecturer, but those options were left blank. Is that bad?

It's for a German scholarship, to do a PhD in Chemistry\Forensics.

Comment: Would you please clarify 1. What's the purpose of the reference letter? 2. Is your friend applying for graduate school? Or applying for something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would presume that what they're asking for is a tl;dr-style summary of your letter into a single sentence:

I emphatically recommend this candidate. I believe they will be top-quality students and practitioners.

I conditionally recommend. The candidate shows a lot of promise but I have these specific concerns; if thus-and-such happens then I would have no hesitations at all, but if it doesn't you might want to think twice.

I recommend without concerns. The candidate shows a lot of promise; they aren't someone whom I'm sure will be at or near the top of the class, but I have no doubt that they will perform very respectably.

Comment: @nateedridge: Not that I can see....?

Comment: Huh.  Either my eyes or my browser deceived me.

Comment: This is also my understanding, but the ordering of the options looks unusual to me. I would expect them to be ordered from strongest to weakest or in the opposite direction, but here it seems like the worst option is the middle one.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the order means anything more than "this is the order I happened to think of them in."